# Read file of client side Python

Tags: python, flask, client-side, readfile

I'm develop a API with function of read a specific file in machine of my users of enterprise, but the api ever return the data of file in server side.

```
  @app.route('/user', methods=['GET'])
  def api_all():
    f = open("C:\\text.txt", "r")
    return jsonify(f.read())
```

how i make the API read the file in client side ?

Comment: Imagine you go to a random web site and the web server starts reading all your files. That shouldn't work, should it? They will have to send the file to your API, actively.

Comment: I agree, but is there any way, creating a totally public archive or something like that to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form with a file upload field. And then e.g. return it as JSON.

Have a look at the newest blog post of Miguel Grinberg, he just wrote about file uploads in Flask:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask